# How to chage width 1024px to 100% in js script

Tags: javascript

```
<script>    
$(function(){
  var slider = new BeaverSlider({
    structure: {
      container: {
        id: "my-slider",
        width: '1024',
        height: 520,

      }
    },
    content: {
      images: [
        "images/slider/1.jpg",
        "images/slider/2.jpg",
        "images/slider/3.jpg",
        "images/slider/4.jpg",
        "images/slider/5.jpg",

        "images/slider/7.jpg",
        "images/slider/8.jpg",
      ]
    },
    animation: {
      effects: effectSets["slider: big set 2"],
      interval: 1000
    }
  });   
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: I take it that this plugin's width parameter requires an integer?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [`screen.width`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_width.asp) instead of 100% that you asked.

```
...
   width: screen.width,
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

```
    id: "my-slider", width: '1024'
```

to:

```
    id: "my-slider", width: '100%'
```

???